# Extract values from an array in mongoDB to dataframe using rmongodb

Tags: arrays, r, mongodb, rmongodb

I'm querying a database containing entries as displayed in the example. All entries contain the following values:

- `_id`: unique id of `overallitem` and `placed_items`
- `name`: the name of te `overallitem`
- `loc`: location of the `overallitem` and `placed_items`
- `time_id`: time the `overallitem` was stored
- `placed_items`: array containing `placed_items` (can range from zero: `placed_items : [],` to unlimited amount.
- `category_id`: the category of the `placed_items`
- `full_id`: the full id of the `placed_items`

I want to extract the `name`, `full_id` and `category_id` on a per `placed_items` level given a `time_id` and `loc` constraint

Example data:

```
{
 "_id" : "5040",
 "name" : "entry1",
 "loc" : 1,
 "time_id" : 20121001,
 "placed_items" : [],
}
{
 "_id" : "5041",
 "name" : "entry2",
 "loc" : 1,
 "time_id" : 20121001,
 "placed_items" : [
  {
   "_id" : "5043",
   "category_id" : 101,
   "full_id" : 901,
  },
  {
   "_id" : "5044",
   "category_id" : 102,
   "full_id" : 902,
  }
 ],
}
{
 "_id" : "5042",
 "name" : "entry3",
 "loc" : 1,
 "time_id" : 20121001,
 "placed_items" : [
  {
   "_id" : "5045",
   "category_id" : 101,
   "full_id" : 903,
  },
 ],
}
```

The expected outcome for this example would be:

```
"name"    "full_id" "category_id"
"entry2"    901         101
"entry2"    902         102
"entry3"    903         101
```

So if `placed_items` is empty, do put the entry in the dataframe and if `placed_items` containts `n` entries, put `n` entries in dataframe

I tried to work out an RBlogger example to create the desired dataframe.

```
#Set up database
    mongo <- mongo.create()

    #Set up condition
    buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "loc", 1)
    mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "time_id")
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$gte", 20120930)
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$lte", 20121002)
    mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
    query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)

    #Count  
    count <- mongo.count(mongo, "items_test.overallitem", query) 

#Note that these counts don't work, since the count should be based on 
#the number of placed_items in the array, and not the number of entries. 

    #Setup Cursor
    cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, "items_test.overallitem", query)
    #Create vectors, which will be filled by the while loop
    name <- vector("character", count)
    full_id<- vector("character", count)
    category_id<- vector("character", count) 

    i <- 1
    #Fill vectors
    while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor)) {
        b <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor)
        order_id[i] <- mongo.bson.value(b, "name")
        product_id[i] <- mongo.bson.value(b, "placed_items.full_id")
        category_id[i] <- mongo.bson.value(b, "placed_items.category_id")
        i <- i + 1
    }
    #Convert to dataframe
    results <- as.data.frame(list(name=name, full_id=full_uid, category_id=category_id))
```

The conditions work and the code works if I would want to extract values on an `overallitem` level (i.e. `_id` or `name`) but fails to gather the information on a `placed_items` level. Furthermore, the dotted call for extracting `full_id` and `category_id` does not seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?